# How to handle trigger error when trigger fired by a process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have an Process setup on ProcessBuilder.
It updates Contact record based on some conditions.

Then Contact after update trigger executes and under that, use cases come and 
we do this `obj.addError('error came due to duplicacy')`;

But As all this is happeening when creating or updating a record at Detail page.
and error comes like this

*Workflow Action Failed to Trigger Flow
The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 301R0000000DNhT. Contact your administrator for help.*

How to handle this gracefully.

Comment: How to handle gracefully? Move all  the logic to a trigger. `Process Builder` was never built to handle errors gracefully, and I doubt if it's a feature that's coming soon.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Logic in trigger only, but trigger is firing error, which is useful when trigger is executed from detail page, but here in my case, trigger is executed through Process builder. and process builder is not able to digest that error :D

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You need to move the logic that is in `Process Builder` to an `Apex Trigger` if you want graceful error handling.

Comment: Yes, That can be done. But anyway Process builder object is different and trigger error object is different.
As Process builder is done by admin not dev and just to handle error, moving the Process builder logic to trigger is not good. 
If i go to debug, i can see the exact error which fired from trigger. I was looking for handling the error at process builder itself.

Comment: It's outside the limits of what `Process Builder` can accomplish.

Comment: If Process Builder's target object is `Foo` and the trigger is on `Bar`, then saving a record on Foo's detail page means you should have a trigger on Foo that checks to make sure that no duplicate Bar _would be_ created and hence  Process Builder never is invoked if there will be a duplicate Bar